# Matplotlib LaTeX: Inconsistent Behaviour with Greek Letters (Specifically \rho)

Tags: python, latex, matplotlib

I'm trying to add some axis-labels to a graph which contains the Greek letter 'rho'. To do this I want to use the LaTeX capability of Matplotlib but it seems to have a problem with the \rho symbol.

Here is a minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import rc,rcParams

rc('text',usetex=True)
rcParams.update({'font.size': 16})

plt.plot([0,1,2,3,4],[0,1,4,9,16])
plt.xlabel('\rho A_i') # works if \rho is replaced with, for example, \sigma
plt.ylabel('Something else')
plt.show()
```

Upon running the first time I get a bunch of LaTeX errors and a blank figure window, running again shows the graph but the xlabel reads '*ho Ai* ' where the *i* is subscript as expected.

The weird thing is if I replace `\rho` with something else, say, `\sigma` it shows up correctly. Can anybody tell me why it is not happy with my code example and how to fix it?

Thanks.

P.s. I tried putting the expression in `$..$` but that changed nothing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you are supposed to use raw strings, and use the $ signs as well. Try:

```
plt.xlabel(r'$\rho A_i$')
```

Comment: That's it thanks. The `$..$` aren't necessary if there's no text following the equation bit. Matplotlib seems to guess where the equation starts.

Answer (score 9):

Be careful when you're using `\n` , `\r` and so on in a string. Those are commands for e.g. entering a new line etc.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

To make sure you don't use these regular expression operators put `\\rho` instead of `\rho`.